# Прошу поправить тэги

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

Репутации пока не хватает - прошу поправить названия тэгов относящихся к версии Delphi. Заменить:

[xe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xe) -> [delphi-xe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe)

[xe7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xe7) -> [delphi-xe7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe7)

Comment: @Nofate: спасибо

Comment: перебил вопросы...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо

Comment: Я думал это какими-то админскими методами решится, чтобы не всплыли все вопросы вверх. Обычно это раздражает людей.

Comment: @KromStern ничего страшного, я думаю. Вопросов не так много, если дадут еще ответы на них, будет только лучше. Просто в таких синонимах смысла не очень много. Тем более что один xe7 попал под interbase-xe7...